# dockerコンテナからホストのautofsでマウント場所にアクセスできない

Tags: docker

CentOS7を使っています。

ホストサーバから

> /mnt/test1 -> 192.168.1.101:/hdd01
>   /mnt/test2 -> 192.168.1.102:/hdd01
>   /mnt/test3 -> 192.168.1.103:/hdd01

でNFSマウントをしています。

ホスト側で

```
$ more /etc/auto.master
/mnt /etc/auto.var    bg,intr --timeout=120 --ghost
$ more /etc/auto.var_dtv
test1 -rw 192.168.1.101:/hdd01
test2 -rw 192.168.1.102:/hdd01
test3 -rw 192.168.1.103:/hdd01
```

というautofsの設定を行なっていてマウントはもちろんのことアクセスができるようになっています。

以下のようなdockerを作成しました。

```
sudo docker run -d --restart=always --privileged --name test -h test -v /mnt/:/mnt/ docker.io/centos /sbin/init
sudo docker exec -it test bash
```

でコンテナの中に入り

```
$ cd /mnt
$ ls
test1 test2 test3
```

という状況ですが、

```
$ cd test1
bash: cd: test1: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

というエラーが発生します。

マウント先の192.168.1.101:/hdd01配下にはそれぞれcontentsというディレクトリがあります。

```
sudo docker run -d --restart=always --privileged --name test -h test -v /mnt/test1/contents/:/mnt/test1/contents/ -v /mnt/test2/contents/:/mnt/test2/contents/ -v /mnt/test3/contents/:/mnt/test3/contents/ docker.io/centos /sbin/init
```

とすればコンテナーの中に入って

```
$ ls /mnt/test1
```

で中身を見ることができます。

しかし、今後マウント先が増えることを考えるとその都度dockerを再構成する必要があり、それは避けたいと思っています。
ホスト側でautofsを使ったものが再起動しなくてもコンテナー内で使用（マウント）できるようにするにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Comment: `sudo docker -run ...` の部分で `-v /mnt/:/mnt/:shared` とするとどうなりますか？(shared option が認識されないかもしれません)

Comment: /usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: linux mounts: Path /mnt is mounted on /mnt but it is not a shared mount..のようなエラーが発生しました。

Comment: 了解です。それでは、`sudo mount --make-rshared /mnt` を実行してから `sudo docker -run ... -v /mnt:/mnt:shared ...` を実行してみて下さい。

Comment: sudo mount --make-rshared /mntを実行してsudo docker run・・・を行いましたが、/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: linux mounts: Path /mnt is mounted on /mnt but it is not a shared mount..との表示です。/mntはshared mountではないと言われているのですが、--make-rsharedが効いていないのでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね、効いていない様ですね…何か分かりましたらまたコメントします。